# Unable to return a default Coder for WithKeys when using @DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Based on the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#schemas-for-pl-types), when using a POJO annotated with `@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)`, schema is available and Beam will know how to serialize these POJOs, no special coders are needed and registration is not required:

> A PCollection with a schema does not need to have a Coder specified,
> as Beam knows how to encode and decode Schema rows; Beam uses a
> special coder to encode schema types.

I don't understand why `WithKeys`, which has an explicit call to `withKeyType()`, when using said POJO, generates this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to return a default Coder for WithKeys/AddKeys/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous).output [PCollection@621486957]. Correct one of the following root causes:
  No Coder has been manually specified;  you may do so using .setCoder().
  Inferring a Coder from the CoderRegistry failed: Cannot provide coder for parameterized type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<K, V>: Unable to provide a Coder for K.
  Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
  See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
  Using the default output Coder from the producing PTransform failed: PTransform.getOutputCoder called.
```

Here is the POJO:

```
@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)
public class Pojo {
  private final long num;
  private final String str;

  @SchemaCreate
  public Pojo(long num, String str) {
    this.num = num;
    this.str = str;
  }

  public long getNum() {
    return this.num;
  }

  public String getStr() {
    return this.str;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object o) {
     ...
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here is a sample contrived pipeline which generates this issue:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();
    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<String> a =
        p.apply(Create.of(List.of("1", "2", "3")).withType(TypeDescriptors.strings()));
    PCollection<String> b =
        p.apply(Create.of(List.of("2", "3", "4")).withType(TypeDescriptors.strings()));

    PCollection<KV<Pojo, String>> a1 =
        a.apply(
            WithKeys.<Pojo, String>of(v -> new Pojo(1, v))
                .withKeyType(TypeDescriptor.of(Pojo.class)));

    PCollection<KV<Pojo, String>> b1 =
        b.apply(
            WithKeys.<Pojo, String>of(v -> new Pojo(1, v))
                .withKeyType(TypeDescriptor.of(Pojo.class)));

    var aTag = new TupleTag<String>();
    var bTag = new TupleTag<String>();
    KeyedPCollectionTuple.of(aTag, a1)  // <== Exception here
        .and(bTag, b1)
        .apply(CoGroupByKey.create())
        .apply(
            ParDo.of(
                new DoFn<KV<Pojo, CoGbkResult>, Integer>() {
                  @ProcessElement
                  public void processElement(ProcessContext context) {
                    var element = context.element();
                    String a = element.getValue().getOnly(aTag, null);
                    String b = element.getValue().getOnly(bTag, null);
                    context.output(a != null && b != null ? 1 : 0);
                  }
                }));
  }
```